# Unable to feed an input into a definition

Tags: python, tkinter, definition

I am struggling with the following problem, I am trying to change an entry box,  however I am trying to create a definition that will change a specific entry box based on which button was pressed. i.e. 5 entry boxes with 5 buttons, once the button is pressed it will change the correlating entry box. I have the definition below to change the entry box and every button feeds into this def.

```
def modifyentry(entry):
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    entry.set(file_path)
```

I have this code in my button:

```
B1 = Button(root, text ="Choose file",command= lambda: modifyentry(e1)).grid(row=1, column=2)
```

So I am passing e1 (the entry box) up to the definition, however I cant get the definition to run the following (which works and changes the entry box to contain the file path):

```
e1.set(file_path)
```

Is anyone able to help me solve this issue please?

Comment: I suspect that you incorrectly initialized `e1` in exactly the same way as you did `B1`, which is always `None` (the result of `.grid()`, NOT the widget itself).

Comment: `e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=entryText1).grid(row=1, column=0)` is how I wrote this, if I change the definition to be `e1.set(file_path)` then it works correctly (but obviously isnt working how I intend it to work), I dont want to have to write a definition for every button

Comment: You have to do the widget creation and the `.grid()` as two separate statements, if you want that variable to actually refer to the widget.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, I want my definition to change entry to e1, everything else works fine. so where it says `entry.set(file_path)` I want it to be `e1.set(file_path)`

Comment: You cannot do anything useful with `e1`, because you're setting it to `None`.

Comment: Hi Jason, I think I realize what you mean, I was asking the button to .set, not the text variable which in this case is called entryText1